# Subtitles in VLC streamer

Tags: mac, vlc-media-player, ipad, subtitles

Does anyone know how to present srt subtitles using VLC media streamer? (iMac to iPad, not that it should matter I guess). I have made sure the subtitle file name is exactly the same as the movie, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC Streamer can use subtitles if you have an srt file to go with the movie you want.

just save the subtitle file 'next' to the movie and VLC will use it automatically when converting.

e.g.

/folder/movie.avi

/folder/movie.srt

the srt file is in the same location as the movie, and has the same name (apart from the filetype).

you will need to delete and re-add the movie after putting the subtitles in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Via the movie submenu you can open the .srt file as subtitle track.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but note that I am working with VLC streamer and not VLC player.